# How can I access SIM applications on my Lumia?

Tags: system-apps, sim

I have applications on my SIM that I need to access. How do I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Windows 10 Mobile**:

Go to Settings → Network & wireless → Mobile & SIM → SIM settings. Tap on "SIM applications".

**In Windows Phone 8.1**:

Go to phone settings → mobile+SIM → SIM settings. Tap on "SIM applications".

**In Windows Phone 8.0**:

Go to phone settings → mobile network. Tap on "SIM applications".

**In Windows Phone 7.x**:

Go to Settings → SIM applications.

Comment: It's interesting how the number of steps required has been steadily increasing...

Answer (score 0):

Download the [SIM Applications](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=0df498ab-54ea-4c37-8d38-aa856180ab27) app provided by Microsoft Mobile Oy.

Using that app you can access the applications on your SIM.

[image]

Comment: If you have Windows 10 mobile, and if you are using edge browser, use this link: https://www.microsoft.com/es-uy/store/p/sim-applications/9wzdncrfhv26 , it will re-direct to the market, now you can use the app, and it's better.